# delete string recursively from all index.php files in a home folder

Tags: shell-scripting

We need a shell script to find and replace a piece of injected code within all index.php files within a /home folder

Comment: Actually what you want is to recover your system from know good backups as you now have no idea what else has been done to your system.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with sed. Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) about it. It may be as simple as `find /home/user -iname index.php -exec sed -i s/<piece of code to find/<replace with that>/ {} \;`

I suggest you to backup before doing that and running some tests to see if it works ok. Remember that the stuff between the / / are regular expressions and depending on its format you may end matching more stuff you need. As I said, test before running this on your 'live' files.

EDIT: fixed the find command, thanks rems

Comment: I think you will need a " \; " at the end of the previous find command after having used the "exec". So " find /home/user -iname index.php -exec sed -i s/<piece of code to find/<replace with that>/ {} \; ".

Comment: Adn if the injected code appears several times on a single line and you want to substitute all of the matches in one line, you will have to add "g" to the "s" command: " find /home/user -iname index.php -exec sed -i s/<piece of code to find/<replace with that>/g {} \; ".

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in $(find /home/user -iname index.php)
do
  echo "replacing in file $file ..."
  sed -i 's/<piece of code to find>/<replace with that>/g' $file
done
```

If you want to **TEST** it first, you may put it first in a temporary file, check if it's correct, and overwrite the original file afterwards:

```
for file in $(find /home/user -iname index.php)
do
  echo "reading from $file, writing to $file.tmp ..."
  sed 's/<piece of code to find>/<replace with that>/g' $file > $file.tmp
done
```

Now go through some of your files and check if the replacement was done correctly. IF everything is ok, then rename the new index.php.tmp files to index.php with

```
for file in $(find /home/user -iname index.php.tmp)
do
  echo "moving $file.tmp to $file ..."
  mv $file.tmp $file
done
```

If the code you want to replace has slashes ( "/" ) in it, then you can use another delimiter in the sed substitute command: 's# piece of code to find # replace with this #g'